# PayPal pay-per-use

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Just wondering has any one ever been able to implement pay-per-use for PayPal billing? I am trying to have customers choose a storage plan.

Ones the customer has decided what plan they want they are charged an initial fee. And then they are charged monthly for the actual storage the used with what ever pricing they have for there plan's usage tier.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't allow this, because "pay-as-you-go" in general leads to too many "I didn't know I was using that much!" disputes

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  The way you have phrased your question, the only valid answers are "Yes" and "No".

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables as explained customer pays an initial fee. Ones they have done that there account is bound to whatever plan they choose. And they are charged in accordance with the plans usage tier pricing. So if the account is basic it will have higher tier price so customer would pay $1 for each GB they host. This will not be the case with the actual pricing because its going to be lower like $0.50/GB

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen so should I have a fixed usage tier instead then? I am starting a small startup with barely any funding and I don't want to end up killing my self with the bill. Nor am I expecting to make allot of profit, hell even if I make $100 month end profit I am happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_adaptivepayments.pdf) will allow you to do exactly what you want, specifically [Preapproval](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/preapproval-api-operation) / [Pay](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/pay-api-operation).

Comment: Thanks because above people started suggesting that this will make confusing but I am not sure how, as the system will display what there monthly bill will look like. This has been done by wireless providers for awhile you don't get a nice bill every time theres long distance and other fun chargers. So I dont see what was a big deal as suggested by above, but thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why they're confused, but Adaptive Payments was introduced specifically for this type of use-case to be available for people.

Comment: Well I am not sure, they started down-voting my post. I am not trying to make a fixed pricing storage because as I said this is a small startup with non-funding or capital other then my own pocket, and I don't want people to pay for what they don't use. I dough you would want to pay for 100 phone min while you only use 60 min. Same with my idea, you pay for what you use and for what you need.